# Homework help yet again please. Recursively multiply Evens?

Tags: java, math, recursion

Below in quotes is my actual assignment and below that is my current code. Can someone point me in the right direction.

> Write a recursive method called multiplyEvens that returns the product of the first n
>   even integers. For example, multiplyEvens(1) returns 2, and multiplyEvens(4) returns 384
>   (because 2 * 4 * 6 * 8 = 384). Throw an IllegalArgumentException if passed a value less then 1.

```
  private static int multiplyEvens(int n)
  {  
      if(n%2 == 0)
      {           
          System.out.println(n*n);
          return multiplyEvens(n*n);
                      // I'm lost
      }
      System.out.println();
      return n; 
  }
```

Comment: I'm so bad at recursion. I'm gonna do this for homework too :p

Comment: Shredder: just let the OP solve the problem for n-1, then you take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(multiplyEvens(4));
}

private static int multiplyEvens(int n) {
    if(n < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value less than 1 not supported");
    else if(n == 1) return 2;
    else return multiplyEvens(n-1) * (n*2);
}
```

Here the basics for recursive algorithms. You have to assume that you have the result calculated for n-1. Then you return the results for n-1 adjusted for n. (That is, you multiply by the nth even number, n*2). The recursive method call does the rest, it in turns assumes it has already computed the value for n-2, etc... until n==0, for which the result is 1

Comment: Post no direct answer (i.e. code) one should not for homework -yoda language-

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay attention to the homework part. My eyes are attracted to code... I will next time. Good point.

Answer (score 5):

Try recursing on n-1 rather than on n*n, and see if you can figure out how the value of `multiplyEvens(n)` relates to `multiplyEvens(n-1)`. Maybe that will give you a start in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

Walk it through on paper.

start with n = 1

```
1%2 = 1 so you don't do into your loop, and return value = 1 (wrong)
```

try n = 2

```
2%2 = 0, so you go into your loop and call multiplyEvens(2*2)
4%2 = 0, so you go into your loop and call multiplyEvens(4*4)
16%2 = 0 ...
```

By now you should be starting to get a clue of at least one problem with your approach...

Answer (score 3):

Anything that can be done recursively can be done iteratively.  Think of it like this:  When you're writing a for-loop, there's an extra value that you need to have before you determine the parity (even/odd) value of whatever value you're working on, up to n.

Since this is homework, here's the broad stroke:

- Your recursive condition may take two parameters instead of one.
- You should multiply values together until some value `i <=n`.

You're mostly there.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it backwards. i.e. on each recursive call, return (2 * n) * recursive call with decreased n. The base case is when n = 1, which the function simply returns 2 without multiplying it with another recursive call (to fulfill that IllegalArgumentException that you need to throw for n < 1).

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying  n evens is the same as
2^n * n!
All you have to do is google 
factorial recursion java

Comment: No, multiplying all even values from 1 to 10 doesn't get me anywhere near 10!.  It's closer to 3,840.

Comment: Makoto: You have the wrong equation. Multiplying the first 10 evens goes from 2 to 20, not even values within 1 to 10. rickz is correct.